# Does my GetEnumerator cause a deadlock?

Tags: c#, deadlock, task-parallel-library, result-partitioning

I am starting to write my first parallel applications. This partitioner will enumerate over a `IDataReader` pulling `chunkSize` records at a time from the data-source.

TLDR; version

```
private object _Lock = new object();
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    var infoSource = myInforSource.GetEnumerator();
                   //Will this cause a deadlock if two threads 
    lock (_Lock)   //use the enumator at the same time?
    {
        while (infoSource.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return infoSource.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

full code

```
protected class DataSourcePartitioner<object[]> : System.Collections.Concurrent.Partitioner<object[]>
{
    private readonly System.Data.IDataReader _Input;
    private readonly int _ChunkSize;
    public DataSourcePartitioner(System.Data.IDataReader input, int chunkSize = 10000)
        : base()
    {
        if (chunkSize < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("chunkSize");
        _Input = input;
        _ChunkSize = chunkSize;
    }

    public override bool SupportsDynamicPartitions { get { return true; } }

    public override IList<IEnumerator<object[]>> GetPartitions(int partitionCount)
    {

        var dynamicPartitions = GetDynamicPartitions();
        var partitions =
            new IEnumerator<object[]>[partitionCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < partitionCount; i++)
        {
            partitions[i] = dynamicPartitions.GetEnumerator();
        }
        return partitions;


    }

    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetDynamicPartitions()
    {
        return new ListDynamicPartitions(_Input, _ChunkSize);
    }
    private class ListDynamicPartitions : IEnumerable<object[]>
    {
        private System.Data.IDataReader _Input;
        int _ChunkSize;
        private object _ChunkLock = new object();
        public ListDynamicPartitions(System.Data.IDataReader input, int chunkSize)
        {
            _Input = input;
            _ChunkSize = chunkSize;
        }

        public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
        {

            while (true)
            {
                List<object[]> chunk = new List<object[]>(_ChunkSize);
                lock(_Input)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < _ChunkSize; ++i)
                    {
                        if (!_Input.Read())
                            break;
                        var values = new object[_Input.FieldCount];
                        _Input.GetValues(values);
                        chunk.Add(values);
                    }
                    if (chunk.Count == 0)
                        yield break;
                }
                var chunkEnumerator = chunk.GetEnumerator();
                lock(_ChunkLock) //Will this cause a deadlock?
                {
                    while (chunkEnumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        yield return chunkEnumerator.Current;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<object[]>)this).GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted `IEnumerable` object it passed back to be thread safe (the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997416.aspx) was so I am assuming PLINQ and TPL could need it) will the lock on `_ChunkLock` near the bottom help provide thread safety or will it cause a deadlock? From the documentation I could not tell if the lock would be released on the `yeld return`.

Also if there is built in functionality to .net that will do what I am trying to do I would much rather use that. And if you find any other problems with the code I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word: **maybe***.

If you're always using this code in the context of a `foreach` loop, then you're not likely to hit *deadlock* (unless it's possible that your `myInfoSource` is infinite, or that your `foreach` loop has some code in it that will never terminate), though you might see slowdowns.

A more likely cause of potential (actually, guaranteed) deadlock would be this:

```
var myObject = new YourObject();
var enumerator = myObject.GetEnumerator();

// if you do this, and then forget about it...
enumerator.MoveNext();

// ...your lock will never be released
```

*I am basing this answer on your initial block of code.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a test framework, it does not deadlock but the second thread will never get data.

```
static void Main()
{
    En en = new En();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (int i in en)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.WriteLine("A:" + i.ToString());
            }
        });
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        foreach (int i in en)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            Console.WriteLine("B:" +i.ToString());
        }
    });
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class En : IEnumerable
{
    object _lock = new object();
    static int i = 0;
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (i < 10)
                    yield return i++;
                else
                    yield break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Returns

```
A:0
A:1
A:2
A:3
A:4
A:5
A:6
A:7
A:8
A:9
```

Here is a updated version of `GetEnumerator` that should behave correctly.

```
public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
{

    while (true)
    {
        List<object[]> chunk = new List<object[]>(_ChunkSize);
        _ChunkPos = 0;
        lock(_Input)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _ChunkSize; ++i)
            {
                if (!_Input.Read())
                    break;
                var values = new object[_Input.FieldCount];
                _Input.GetValues(values);
                chunk.Add(values);
            }
            if (chunk.Count == 0)
                yield break;
        }
        var chunkEnumerator = chunk.GetEnumerator();
        while (true)
        {
            object[] retVal;
            lock (_ChunkLock)
            {
                if (chunkEnumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    retVal = chunkEnumerator.Current;
                }
                else 
                    break; //break out of chunk while loop.
            }
            yield return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```